# Effect of Misclassification Cost on SVM

Tags: classification, svm, roc, unbalanced-classes

I am using Matlab to train an SVM for very unbalanced data.

However, my concern is not so much for the particular class assignment (ie 1/0), but rather to the scores (the prethreshold continuous SVM output). Practically, I measure the performance of the SVM using ROC curves which only care about the relative magnitudes/ordering of the SVM scores.

My question is, if I were to change the misclassifcation cost, as commonly done with unbalanced data, would that only change the SVM decision boundary or the actual ordering of the scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the ordering as well, since the orientation of the hyperplane typically changes when you fiddle with the cost function. Translating the separating hyperplane in feature space does not induce changes to ROC curves, but rotating it does.

Comment: So then my understanding is that this adds another free parameter to the SVM tuning procedure (RBF sigma, C, & misclassification cost). Is there any easier way to tune this as opposed to a 3D grid search?

Comment: @DankMasterDan Yes, this adds another hyperparameter. It is much better to use tuning libraries to optimize all hyperparameters instead of grid search. Have a look at [Optunity](http://docs.optunity.net).

Comment: thnx alot @Marc !