# Effect of Gamma and C on distant points in SVM

Tags: variance, svm, bias, kernel-trick

(I am aware of the following, already answered questions: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/the-role-of-gamma-c-in-svm),[and this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126826/effect-of-misclassification-cost-on-svm),as well as others, and IMHO they are not related)

I am trying to precisely understand the behavior of SVM's with regards to the gamma hyperparameter. I came across [this site](https://github.com/qingkaikong/blog/tree/master/45_support_vector_machine_part2_sklearn) in which there are two classes, a blue and a red.

One can see that when C = 1,

- with gamma = 5, any point that is not in the close vicinity of a **blue dot** is considered red, (blue decides what is, and red takes the rest)
- but with gamma = 50, the tendency is reversed, and any point that is not in the close vicinity of a **red dot** is considered blue. (red decides what is red, blue takes the rest).
  [image]
  [image]

When one fixes gamma to be 0.5 and varies C, one sees a similar pattern: for C =1 or C =100, red takes the "rest", but when C is 10000, then blue takes the "rest". 
[image: C=1]
[image]

- Is there some deep insight that I am missing? Is this completely
  serendipitous?
- Is it possible to predict which class would take "the
  rest"?
- Can there be several back and forth between the two scenarios
  (i.e: for C = 20k, red goes back to "taking the rest", and for C=30k,
  it's blue again, etc.) or is there theoretically just one "flip"
  possible?